# Iterate through a list and populate a resulting list [Haskell]

Tags: haskell

I would like to do the following:

```
let a = [1,2,3,4]
let res = []

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (someFilterFunction(x) == true) {
    res.push(a[i])
  }
}

return res
```

In Haskell, I assumed it would use `takewhile` but I need the function to not skip when the condition is not met.

Comment: This is just [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter).

Comment: even in Javascript, you should use the `filter` method rather than an explicit loop for this!

Comment: And BTW, it is almost _never_ necessary to write `== true`, neither in Haskell nor in other programming languages. `if (someFilterFunction(x)) {...}` does the same thing. (In JavaScript it _might_ make sense to write `=== true` though, to avoid the quirks of its bonkers implicit type conversion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would like to do the following in Haskell: Write a function that takes a list as input, checks each element if it matches some test (aka predicate, filter function), include the element in a result list if the test succeeds.

So we want a function that accepts a list of some type of values (let's call them Ints) and returns a list:

```
timothyylim :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

That's the type signature (like a C prototype).  Now we need the declaration.  Because you are learning Haskell lets define this function without using any of the built in operations. What do we do when the input list is empty?  Return an empty list!

```
timothyylim [] = []
```

What do we do when the list has at least one element?

```
timothyylim (firstElement : restOfList) =
    -- What goes here?
```

Well we want to check if `someFilterFunction firstElement` is true and include that element along with the rest of the filtered list.

```
    if someFilterFunction firstElement
        then firstElement : timothyylim restOfList
```

And if it is false, then we just want to return the rest of the filtered list without this element.

```
        else timothyylim restOfList
```

At this point we're done - we have a new function `timothyylim` that applies `someFilterFunction` to a list and generates a new list.  There was no need to look at Prelude functions such as `takeWhile` - we did this using only language primitives including (in order of introduction) a type signature, case-by-case function declaration, pattern matching, if-then-else statements, function application, list concatenation, and primitive recursion.

**In Real Use**

In Haskell there is already a definition of a function named `filter`.  It's like our filter except you'd pass in the filter function `someFilterFunction` as a parameter.  So we could say:

```
timothyylim inputList = filter someFilterFunction inputList
```

Or equivalently:

```
timothyylim = filter someFilterFunction
```

Most of the time if your solution is a manual primitive recursive function, such as the `timothyylim` function above, then there's already a higher order function (i.e. a function that takes another function as a parameter) in Prelude that can do the job for you (see folds, maps, filters, and zips).